# Как вызвать метод заполнения фигуры цветом с разной реализацией в зависимости от истинности условия?

Tags: java, swing

При нажатии на кнопку "заполнить красным" и "заполнить желтым", квадрат должен заливаться или красным, или желтым соответственно. В констуктор ButtonActionListener я передаю параметр - номер, который соответствует определенной кнопке. И далее нужно вызвать методы для заполнения определенным цветом в зависимости от номера (1 - желтый, 2- красный). Но заливки не происходит, не пойму почему. По идее, нужно как-то paintComponent, который переопределен в классе Action, отдельно вызвать, но как это сделать? Подскажите

Код:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Forma {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    public MyFrame() {
        setSize(width, height);
        MyPanel panel = new MyPanel();
        this.add(panel);
        JButton yellow = new JButton("Заповнити жовтим");
        JButton red = new JButton("Заповнити червоним");
        //JButton title = new JButton("Додати напис");
        panel.add(yellow);
        panel.add(red);
        //panel.add(myTitle);
        ButtonActionListener listener1 = new ButtonActionListener(1);
        ButtonActionListener listener2 = new ButtonActionListener(2);
        //ButtonActionListener listener3 = new ButtonActionListener(3);
        yellow.addActionListener(listener1);
        red.addActionListener(listener2);
        //myTitle.addActionListener(listener3);     
    }
    static public int width = 700;
    static public int height = 700;
}
class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g.drawRect(250, 70, 200, 200);  
    }
}
class ButtonActionListener implements ActionListener {
    int number;
    public ButtonActionListener(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }       
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        class Action extends JPanel {
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                if (number == 1) 
                    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
                else
                    g.setColor(Color.red);
                g.fillRect(250, 70, 200, 200);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А как ты получаешь новую панель, вот её и надо добавлять

Answer (score 0):

Для установки цвета панели используйте `panel.setBackground(Color.yellow)`